# Center a layout in Android?

Tags: android

I have a linear layout, how can I add gravity to it so that it is horizontally centred?

```
LinearLayout textHolder = new LinearLayout(context);
 textHolder.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

The above does not appeat to work.

Comment: If you want to use a tag in your title, make it fit in a sentence. Please don't prefix your titles with tag names, it's redundant.

Comment: @Mat, are you going to go edit all his other questions as well? :)

Comment: @jeffamaphone: no, I'm a maniac, but not _that_ much (:

Comment: Do you have to do this in java or would it be possible to use xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
LinearLayout textHolder = new LinearLayout(context);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
lp.gravity = Graviity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
textHolder.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

But this will only center the children of the linearlayout according to textHolder's size. If you want to center the textHolder completely, the you should apply the layout params to the parent of textHolder.